# Using the Ionic Auth Service and my custom API

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-auth-service

Many mobile apps require user login. That's why Ionic launched their Auth service (https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/). I can create users via the Auth service itself or via the Ionic API. I also can save custom data for each user. Very nice is also that I can sen targeted push notifications to my users. Seems like a nice out-of-the-box solution.

But most of the time apps have more complex logic (user can post something, user can order something, make a payment, ...). The simple user with some atributes from Ionic does not help much in those cases.

So I need to authorize the users not only inside the app but also against some custom API. And this is where my questions come up...what's the best way to do this?

Some things that came to my mind:

- When creating the user in Ionic, also create the same user with the same email and password in my API. So I can make authorized requests. But this does not user any token and I would have to pass my password in every request, also I am worried about data consistency. What if the user changes its password?
- Use the internal Ionic user ID, create one global token and use user ID and global token to authenticate the user in my API. But is this secure?

Another worry in my mind: If I save user name, email etc in the Ionic Auth system I would have to access it via their API every time I need it in my own system. For example: A user orders a product in the app. Then my system needs to send out a confirmation to the user. I would have to access the Ionic API to know that users email...and so own.

I think this is all confusing.

- Is Ionic Auth not made for those situation? Then, I don't see what it's made for at all...
- Is ionic Auth just not there yet...?
- Am I just not getting it?

Comment: https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/custom-auth.html